# opening a shell and interact with using Java

Tags: java, bash, shell, processbuilder

I had previously asked the same question but with no answer, and have found some other questions similar to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188362/using-xterm-with-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431473/opening-a-shell-and-interacting-with-its-i-o-in-java) but again with no appropriate answers.
Can anyone please help me out with this. I am trying to open a shell from Java and interact with it (write commands and read the shell's output). The commands will be given by the user like changing directory, compiling a C program etc. The command list is not fixed.

I have also tried and use the /bin/bash -c  method and the following as well.

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("xterm").start();

Process p = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash").start();
```

Thanks and I hope that the problem is clear.

Comment: Should your Java program be a "director" for the shell being executed, or it's intended to run a shell and provide a user ability to interact with it?

Comment: I want to start the shell with some directory redirected (Java will change the directory of the shell using cd command). Once started, I want that the user can interact with it.

Comment: If you want to start an interractive shell, you really need to start a virtual terminal, just the shell is not enough. The shell only processes commands, starts processes and ties them together, but it isn't what displays the output in a box

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for? Maybe there is another way to do it. There are several java implementations of interactive shells, such as java shell http://java-shell.sourceforge.net/  rhino https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rhino/Shell and http://www.beanshell.org/

Comment: I wish to develop a C program profiler in Java. For proper module development it will be useful if the user can compile and execute the C code via the GUI provided itself without separately opening the bash terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Example of workable solution will be almost like below

```
   Process process;

   rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

try 
{

    process = rt.exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","ls -al /home/"});

    log.warn("message to display");

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

    String line=null;

    while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {

        log.warn(line);
    }

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();

    log.warn("Exited with error code : "+ exitVal);

}
catch (IOException e) 
{
    log.warn("IO Execption 1 Happen : " + e.getMessage());
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    log.warn("Execption Happen : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what the poster asked for, but I still think it's cool that it worked.

Comment: I had already tried this method, but still thanks for trying.